# Finding if a function is in some space and derivation of a Dirac delta function

Tags: distribution-theory

First of all, my English is very bad, sorry.

It is likely that we'll be asked something similar in an exam tomorrow, and I m totally not equipped to solve this exercise (i.e. I don't have the prerequisite) .

I'll sum this up, I don't know about mathjax or anyway to write mathematics symbols here yet, sorry.

${}$

Let $f$ be the most simple real function you will meet in an exam.

Is it in $L_2$?

Derivate it

Is it in $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ ?

Derivation again

Is it in $H^2(\mathbb{R})$ ?

There's no need to be very formal, I believe teacher just look at the answers and doesn't care much about explanations

Here's more details about how it's going

So there are two single variable real function
$f_1 = 1$ when $x$ in $[0,1]$, and $0$ elsewhere 
$f_2 = \frac{1}{2}(x+|x|)$ for $x$ in $[-1,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere ( basically $x $ between $0$ and $1$ and $0$ elsewhere)

$1)$ Are these functions in $H^2(\mathbb{R})$ ?

OK I THINK

I think yes because there's no divergence for the sum (integration) of their square  in their intervals

$2)$ Derivation of these functions. OK

_First one is a Dirac at $x=0$ minus a Dirac at $x=1$

_Second one is $1$ minus a Dirac at $x=1$

$3)$ are $f_1$ and $f_2$ in $H (\mathbb{R})$ ?

NOT OK

I don't even know what is $H$ !

I ended up thinking its some Hilbert space but maybe it's Sobolev's maybe it's Hardy's (doesn't look like it's this one tho)

So after some researches I tried to see if they have a norm well defined on theirs intervals but it doesn't look like it as Dirac can be dealt with that easily when integrated

There is a story about a test function and it is most likely this I should have learn about back when I had a few hours to think about it

$4)$ derivation of these functions again. NOT OK

I have no idea, I'm tempted to say that when you do the derivation of a Dirac it is a Dirac again but that is just instinct.

It looks like it works for $0$ because of the following

A Dirac at $0$ I think I can just say it is equal to $e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$ but the two minus Diracs at $x= 1$ got my number.

$5)$ are $f_1$ and $f_2$  in $H^2(\mathbb{R})$ ?

Even if I found the second derivatives I'd be clueless. Don't even know what $H$ is as there's no mention of it in the material the teacher put online.

Thanks for attention!

Edit : sorry for tagging it in group-theory

Comment: I thought about it a bit more. If I can shift the exp(i*pi/2) along x axis I'm done with the derivation part. I figured a function that can be primitive of a Dirac delta

Comment: Edit 5: actually that exp is a constant.. Nevermind I'm just dumb

Comment: Click on "edit/improve" at the bottom of the other questions to see how we type in Mathjax